# How many unique ways are there to achieve a score in Football?

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Challenge: given a number, calculate how many unique, order-independent ways there are to achieve a score of that number in American Football.

Let's see how few characters can be used in each of your favorite languages! The usual rules apply.  Input and output in a way that is natural to your language.

Recall that the ways to score in Football are safety (2 points), field goal (3 points), touchdown (6 points), touchdown + extra point (7 points), and touchdown + 2-point conversion (8 points).

For example, given 9 as input, the program should return 4, since you could score:

- 1 touchdown + extra point and 1 safety
- 1 touchdown and 1 field goal
- 3 field goals
- 3 safeties and 1 field goal

Note that order does not matter.

Comment: I'm not familiar with American Football. Is the question just about ways of partitioning the number using 2,3,6,7 and 8?

Comment: @swish yup!  Just an actual version of the problem I found myself thinking about.

Comment: This is essentially identical to [Need change of 78 cents](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/need-change-of-78-cents) except for the values of some constants. (Although on reflection, since this question is better posed, it might be preferable to close the other one as a duplicate of this one).

Comment: Awhh. I watch the Canadian Football League. I want my 1 point for punting into the endzone!

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica - 42

```
Length@IntegerPartitions[#,∞,{2,3,6,7,8}]&
```

## Prolog - 140

Never wrote anything in Prolog before, just knew that this problem should be quite nice for it.

```
p(0,_,[]).
p(N,[H|T],O):- N>=H,p(N,T,O). 
p(N,[H|S],[H|T]):- N>=H,M is N-H,p(M,[H|S],T).
f(N,C):- aggregate(count,X^p(N,[2,3,6,7,8],X),C).

?- f(9,C).
C = 4.
```

Comment: I only see 42 chars. Does this have something to do with the unicode character?

Comment: @Cruncher Oh, I forgot to put `f=` at the start, so it would be a function definition.

Answer (score 0):

### Python - 146

```
t=int(input())
from itertools import*
print len([a for a in chain(*(combinations_with_replacement([2,3,6,7,8],n) for n in range(t)))if sum(a)==t])
```

Comment: Instead of `from itertools import ...`, you can use `from itertools import*`. You only use `combinations_with_replacement` once, so having to use it wouldn't cost you after this change.

Comment: True, I'll change it, thanks!